# Why does common lisp's case construct always match True (T)?

Tags: common-lisp, case

This is with SBCL 1.0.55 on Debian squeeze. I'm probably missing something obvious, but I'm a beginner, so please bear with me.

```
CL-USER> (defparameter x 0)

CL-USER> (case x (t 111) )
111
```

So it looks like case here is matching the variable `x` with the truth symbol `t`. This happens with everthing I've tried; this `x` is just an example. I don't see why this would happen. Since `case` uses `eql` for matching, I tried

```
CL-USER> (eql x t)
NIL
```

So, eql does not match `x` and `t`. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `case` construct in Common Lisp, `t`, used by itself, is equivalent to `default` in C; that is, it's evaluated if the expression doesn't match any of the other cases. If you want to match the actual symbol `t`, use `(t)` instead.

Comment: Thnaks. I've had difficulty finding documentation about this. Can you point me to a reference?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the spec, but can you point me to the relevant line(s), please?

Comment: OK, never mind, I guess "In the case of case, the symbols t and otherwise may not be used as the keys designator. To refer to these symbols by themselves as keys, the designators (t) and (otherwise), respectively, must be used instead." are the relevant lines. Sorry, guess I missed that.

Answer (score 7):

Described in the [CASE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_case_.htm#case) documentation.

**otherwise-clause::= ({otherwise | t} form*)**

The syntax says that an otherwise clause is either `(otherwise form-1 ... form-n)` or `(t form-1 ... form-n)`. Note that the syntax says `{otherwise | t}`. The vertical bar is an OR in a syntax specification. So the marker for an otherwise clause is either `otherwise` or `t`.

That means, if your `case` clause begins with `otherwise` or `t`, then we have an `otherwise-clause`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit? The lines that I quoted above look like the relevant ones, and I'm not using the otherwise clause here anyway.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that clarification. The implication of the sentence you quoted was not obvious to non-experts. Does that means that any case clause that follows one beginning with t is silently ignored? Just to be clear, the case you are referencing is the one that I actually used in my question, namely `(case x (t 111) )`, right? The expression I "meant" to use, namely `(case x ((t) 111) )`, does *not* correspond to an otherwise clause, correct?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: if you look at the syntax description of CASE in the HyperSpec page I mentioned in my answer, you see that CASE does only allow one otherwise clause and it has to be the last clause. ((t) ...) is not an otherwise clause, right.

Comment: Right. My question is what would happen if the t/otherwise clause did not come last. To my surprise, the compiler does not issue any warnings, and at runtime the `t` clause is ignored. Eg. with `(defparameter x 2)` and `(defun foo (y)
(case y
  (t (print "matches t"))
  (1 (print "matches 1"))
  )
)` `(foo x)` gives `nil`. If the t clause it moved to the end, it matches. I would have expected a warning here.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: according to the standard it seems legal to do something unspecified. It would be great if an implementation informs the user about that problem. You might want to contact the maintainers of your Lisp compiler and propose that a warning (or even an error) gets shown. Clozure CL shows a warning and LispWorks an error during compilation.

Comment: Ok, I'll write to SBCL. Thanks. PS. I also get an error from CLISP (`*** - CASE: the T clause must be the last one
`).

Comment: Reported as [Compiler does not give error if T clause in case construct is not last one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/959687). Also, GCL gives "matches t", which looks wrong to me. Should I report that?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: I'm not sure if GCL is still maintained. But I would also there prefer that it does inform the user during compilation. It would also be great if it would detect that problem and signal an error.

Comment: I sent a message to gcl-devel, but I must say the project doesn't look very active.